# Meteor: Use data in child template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using the main template to get the data from the DB. But now I want to use the data also in the child template. But this doesn't work as The `h1`-title is shown, but the `input`-field is empty:

**template**

```
<template name="main">
    <h1>{{result.title}}</h1>

    {{ > child}}
</template>

<template name="child">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{result.title}}"></td>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.main.helpers({
    result: function() { return Template.instance().result(); }
});

Template.main.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;
    var id = 123;

    instance.autorun(function () {
        var subscription = instance.subscribe('anything', id);
    });

    instance.result = function() { return Collection.findOne({ _id: id }); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the template data in a child template by using the context of `../`:

```
<template name="child">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{../result.title}}"></td>
</template>
```

Comment: This seems not working for this instance subscription. Instead I have to use `{{>child result=result}}`. But I don't understand why.